# Trying to understand pandas dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a space-delimited `.dat` file, for which the first few lines look like this:

```
1 SDSSJ000005.95+145310.1 2.49900 * 0.000e+00 0.00 NA -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 0.000 0.000 NONE 
4 SDSSJ000009.27+020621.9 1.43200 UvS 0.000e+00 0.00 NA -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 0.000 0.000 NONE 
5 SDSSJ000009.38+135618.4 2.23900 QSO 0.000e+00 0.00 NA -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 0.000 0.000 NONE 
6 SDSSJ000011.37+150335.7 2.18000 * 0.000e+00 0.00 NA -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 0.000 0.000 NONE 
11 SDSSJ000030.64-064100.0 2.60600 QSO 0.000e+00 0.00 NA -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 15.460 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 23.342 56.211 UV 
15 SDSSJ000033.05+114049.6 0.73000 UvS 0.000e+00 0.00 NA -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 0.000 0.000 NONE 
27 LBQS2358+0038 0.95000 QSO 0.000e+00 0.00 NA 17.342 18.483 18.203 17.825 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 23.301 56.572 UV
```

They're astronomical measurements, and there are 29008 lines in the file. When I read the file with

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('todo.dat', sep = ' ',
                   names = ['no', 'NED', 'z', 'obj_type','S_21', 'power',
                            'SI_flag','U_mag', 'B_mag', 'V_mag', 'R_mag',
                            'K_mag', 'W1_mag', 'W2_mag', 'W3_mag', 'W4_mag',
                            'L_UV', 'Q', 'flag_uv'])
```

the dataframe shows `[29008 rows x 19 columns]`. I want to organise the data based on the column headed `z` (which is the third column -- index 2). Adding `index_col='z'` to the `read_csv` call gives me a  `KeyError: 'z'` error, but using index_col = 2 doesn't give me an error. I thought pandas labelled the headers like a dictionary, so `'z'` should be the key in the dictionary for that column. So why do I get an error when I refer to index 2 as 'z'?

Comment: The simple reason is because `index_col` expects an int or sequence of ints as argument - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html.  
Now, why it doesn't accept column names, it's probably how it is implemented.

Comment: @Shiva Actually [`read.csv index_col` argument has been accepting string or list-of-string for some time, but the doc was never been updated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22276). At least that works for column-names from the header. OP is saying this breaks on column-names passed via `names`? OP can you please confirm this on current (0.23)? If so, that deserves a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)

Comment: Is 'SDSSJ000005.95+145310.1' really your second column 'NED', or is it split according to some fixed-format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this seems buggy, and possibly related to [this issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/714). An easy work around is just to use `set_index` afterhand:

```
data = pd.read_csv('todo.dat', sep = ' ',
                   names = ['no', 'NED', 'z', 'obj_type','S_21', 'power',
                            'SI_flag','U_mag', 'B_mag', 'V_mag', 'R_mag',
                            'K_mag', 'W1_mag', 'W2_mag', 'W3_mag', 'W4_mag',
                            'L_UV', 'Q', 'flag_uv']).set_index('z')
```

Comment: It's not related to the bug you mentioned, because that's about the dask backend. I've been trying to repro it on pandas itself. It seems to happen when len(names), minus one for the index_col, is shorter than the number of columns in the data.