# Pandas not handling file as expected

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a file containing astronomical data that I need to plot. The first few lines look like this:

```
1 SDSSJ000005.95+145310.1 2.49900 * 0.000e+00 0.00 NA -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 0.000 0.000 NONE 
4 SDSSJ000009.27+020621.9 1.43200 UvS 0.000e+00 0.00 NA -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 0.000 0.000 NONE 
5 SDSSJ000009.38+135618.4 2.23900 QSO 0.000e+00 0.00 NA -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 0.000 0.000 NONE 
6 SDSSJ000011.37+150335.7 2.18000 * 0.000e+00 0.00 NA -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 0.000 0.000 NONE 
11 SDSSJ000030.64-064100.0 2.60600 QSO 0.000e+00 0.00 NA -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 15.460 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 23.342 56.211 UV 
15 SDSSJ000033.05+114049.6 0.73000 UvS 0.000e+00 0.00 NA -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 0.000 0.000 NONE 
27 LBQS2358+0038 0.95000 QSO 0.000e+00 0.00 NA 17.342 18.483 18.203 17.825 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 -999.000 23.301 56.572 UV
```

I'm trying to set the third column (the first row's value being z = 2.49900) as the index, since this is the column that I'll be plotting against. The columns starting -999.000 are the values that I'll be processing and plotting.

My problem is, that pandas isn't processing the file as I'd expect. I'm using

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('todo.dat', sep = ' ',
                   names = ['no', 'NED', 'z', 'obj_type','S_21', 'power',
                            'SI_flag','U_mag', 'B_mag', 'V_mag', 'R_mag',
                            'K_mag', 'W1_mag', 'W2_mag', 'W3_mag', 'W4_mag',
                            'L_UV', 'Q', 'flag_uv'])

data.set_index('z')
```

to read the file into a dataframe, and it's giving me the following:

[image]

but I would expect the `Index` column to be `1, 2, 3, 4, ...` and the `'no'` column to be `1, 4, 5, 6, ...` as in the file.

How do I prevent the first column in my file being interpreted as the index? I want to preserve the numbering of the lines as they are.

I've asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51432925/trying-to-understand-pandas-dataframes) but the answers didn't help.

Comment: You can adding `index_col =False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make `'z'` the index of your data frame because indices can only be integers or sequences (`'z'` is a float value, so it cannot be the index).

If `'z'` was an integer/sequence, you'd want to try:

```
data = pd.read_csv('todo.dat', sep = ' ', index_col = 'z',
                   names = ['no', 'NED', 'obj_type','S_21', 'power',
                            'SI_flag','U_mag', 'B_mag', 'V_mag', 'R_mag',
                            'K_mag', 'W1_mag', 'W2_mag', 'W3_mag', 'W4_mag',
                            'L_UV', 'Q', 'flag_uv'])
```

Comment: `data = pd.read_csv('todo.dat', sep = ' ',
                   names = ['no', 'NED', 'z', 'obj_type','S_21', 'power',
                            'SI_flag','U_mag', 'B_mag', 'V_mag', 'R_mag',
                            'K_mag', 'W1_mag', 'W2_mag', 'W3_mag', 'W4_mag',
                            'L_UV', 'Q', 'flag_uv'], index_col = False).set_index('z')`

seems to have worked to align the columns as I wanted, and also to make the `z` column the index, although I can't inspect it with something like `max(data['z'])`. Why do you say I can't use it as an index?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on my pandas, but I said you can't use it as an index because indices can only be integers and sequences.  `'z'` is not an integer (though you could make it an integer it by multiplying by a power of 10).  Also, you should make a duplicate column of your index if you want to inspect it.